# multithreading on a programme which only scans for new file and download it than upload it to other place

Tags: multithreading, performance, concurrency, operating-system

For example I have a single core machine. My programme needs to scan a website and looking for new file. Whenever it finds a new file, it will download the file and upload to somewhere else.

Now I have two options for implementing my programme:

Option 1: Create one thread for scanning the website. This thread will be scheduled to run every second. Whenever it finds a new file, it will spawn a new thread for downloading the file and upload it. (e.g. if it scans 5 new files it will spawn 5 threads + 1 original scanner thread)

Option 2: Just create 2 threads, 1 for scanning, another for downloading and uploading. Other files will be put into queue.

Which option is more make sense? In my opinion i think option 2 makes more sense because online 1 thread can use the file and internet i/o one of the time, bunch of threads only make context swithcing occur frequently and create overhead. Am I right?

Comment: hello? can anyone help me?

Comment: Without specifying an operating system, a program language, a library which you want to use,it is impossible to decide which method is the best one. (E.g. many languages provides "tasks" and similar mechanisms, which far more convenient for programming than low-level threads). Also, for most of performance questions only a **testing** can give an answer.